# Persistent time_t warning using system_clock::to_time_t

Tags: c++, time, warnings

The function i have written below is an attempt to allow for 32-bit and 64-bit times in and effort to be more flexible. I'm getting a persistent warning regarding a loss of data conversion that doesn't quite make sense.

```
time_t now()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;

        system_clock::time_point time_point = system_clock::now();            
        time_t now_time = system_clock::to_time_t(time_point);     
        return now_time;   //warning appears here
    }
```

The warning: warning C4244: '=': conversion from '__time64_t' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
is found on the to_time_t. What i'm confused about is that the cppreference indicates that to_time_t returns a time_t, but when i navigate to the actual function, it indicates that it is forced to a 64-bit time.

So, any idea what might be causing this? Also, i'm open to cleaner implementations of getting the system time and returning out a time_t.

I'd also like to add that the example matches what is found here:
[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: no. The warning remains

Comment: I'm using vs2015, compiling in mixed platform debug on a win 10 64-bit machine.

Comment: fyi MSVC2017 clean compile: https://godbolt.org/g/pue3h5

Comment: What do you call a _mixed platform_?

Comment: Updated the OP to show the warning location.

Comment: Weird.  Even the [MSVS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874826.aspx) says it should return a `time_t`.  Must be a bug in the implementation

Comment: @RichardCritten - I don't have 2017, and can't use it for the time being.

This is a standalone module, and when i tried moving to x64 compilation, it complained of no entry point.

Comment: @Jason and the above online compiler does not have MSVC2015, was just posted for info.

Comment: @RichardCritten - gotcha. As expected, it did not see issues.

Comment: Another approach would be to never convert to `time_t` at all and abandon the C timing API altogether.  That is the approach taken here:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 0):

This is really probable you ran into a documented bug of MSVC 2015. The bad news is it as been documented in the now retired Microsoft Connect.

It was at the url https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1355735/breaking-change-in-vs-2015-chrono-steady-clock-time-point-not-longer-convertible-to-system-clock-time-point (dead); reported 05/22/15--06:42.

Comment: And in true MS form they used a "Moved Permanently" redirect when a 404 would have been more appropriate. As such, archive.org thinks the page still exists. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a preprocessor definition that set the _USE_32BIT_TIME_T. I didn't see it when i was searching, but that appears to be what is forcing the time_t to use 32-bit. As to why the to_time_t function returns 64-bit, i think i found somewhere that it is forced to 64-bit when running on 64-bit windows.

If anyone can track that down, it would be good to have here for posterity. I'm almost 100% sure i had seen that but i can't find it now.